# ローカルにある画像ファイルを読み込む方法

Tags: unity3d, unity2d

[マルチポスト](https://teratail.com/questions/132975)

Unity製のアプリ（PC,Mac&Linux Standaloneの中でwindows向けのビルド）で、ユーザからPC内の画像を取得する方法が知りたいです。

webブラウザなどであれば、以下の画像のような機能があると思いますが、同様のものはあるのでしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]